# Is there any way to input a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, input

Is there any alternative way to input a string (along with blank spaces) without using **`std::string`** in C++?

I know, **`std::string`** is the standard way. But, I am just curious.

Comment: What delimits your string?  newline?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the string-class? It's part of standard C++ for a reason!

Comment: Might as well have just said you're using C…

Answer (score 2):

`std::istream::getline(char *, streamsize)`

Stolen shamelessly from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

```
// istream getline
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  char name[256], title[256];

  cout << "Enter your name: ";
  cin.getline (name,256);

  cout << "Enter your favourite movie: ";
  cin.getline (title,256);

  cout << name << "'s favourite movie is " << title;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And then someone enters a line longer than 256 characters...

Comment: What sort of trouble? And, why are you flushing the input stream?

Answer (score 2):

By using `std::string`. There is no reason not to use it.

If, by some obscure chance, you have additional requirements why you cannot use `std::string`, please state those requirements as they will impact the code.

Update: If the input is newline delimited, use `string s; std::getline(cin, s);`

Comment: The question states very clearly to not use the string class.

Comment: @Mysticial So? If the OP states **why** he cannot use the string class, we might find an error in his thinking. Maybe the OP incorrectly thinks that `cin >> s` is the only way to input a `std::string`, in which case my answer will solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getline` - the old C way of doing things. But why would you want to do this?

Ref: http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html

Or if you like headaches you could even use system calls!